# viewWillAppear called but viewDidAppear not called after pushViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, pushviewcontroller

In my app, sometimes pushViewController fails for no reason and what happens is very weird. The navigationBar and navigationItem change but the `ViewController` is not pushed. Then I can tap nothing on the screen. I find that `viewWillAppear` is called but `viewDidAppear` isn't called. I push the home button of iPhone to enter background. After entering foreground again, the `ViewController` is pushed and `viewDidAppear` is called. I don't know why and when it happens.

[normal viewDidAppear callstack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPPjV.png)

[viewDidAppear after enterBackground callstack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLrQo.png)

Comment: Please overwrite `didRecieveMemoryWarning` and check if this method gets invoked

Comment: And please check your pushedFromView reference is still retained ?

Comment: Also check if you are calling the same methods on super class. Like `[super viewWillAppear]` and `[super viewDidAppear]` in the respective functions.

Comment: Are you doing anything in your `viewWillAppear`, `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, `viewDidLayoutSubviews`,  or `updateViewContraints` (or any of the methods they call) that would block, loop forever, or the like? If you break in the debugger at that point, what does the call stack look like?

Comment: `didRecieveMemoryWarning` doesn't get invoked. PushedFromView is still retained. The super class of viewController is `UIViewController`.

Comment: @jcaron I set navigationBar tintColor in `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: Please provide all relevant code, you're obviously doing something out of the ordinary.

Comment: @SahebRoy didRecieveMemoryWarning doesn't get invoked.

Comment: @Gihan PushedFromView is still retained.

Comment: @Vishal The super class of viewController is UIViewController.

Comment: @jcaron  `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated { [super viewWillAppear:animated]; [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:NO]; _navigationBarConfig = config; for (UIView * subView in self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews) if ([subView isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"_UINavigationBarBackground")]) { subView.alpha = config.hide?(config.alpha):1; } }`

Comment: Please update your question to add the code there rather than put it in a comment, it'll be much easier to read...

Comment: Also, how do you know `viewDidAppear` isn't called? Breakpoint? Logs? Anything in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, `updateViewContraints`? As already requested, if you break in the debugger at that point, what does the call stack look like?

Comment: @jcaron I cleaned my code. There's nothing but `[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:attributes]` in `viewWillAppear`. And I just `setFrame` of some subviews in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`. I do nothing in `viewDidLayoutSubviews ` and `updateViewContraints `.

Comment: @jcaron I uploaded the picture of call stack. Every time `viewDidAppear` is called when the app enter background. And the call stack look like what the picture shows. Then the vc can be pushed when the app enter foreground again.

Answer (score 1):

If you can repro by:

1. Try using the left edge pop gesture when there are no view
   controllers below it (i.e on root view controllers, your VC-Home
   controller)
2. Try clicking on any UI elements after this.

Then Disable  **interactivePopGestureRecognizer** when current viewController is the firstVC in navigation controller.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
}
```

reference:
[iOS App Freezes on PushViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36503224/ios-app-freezes-on-pushviewcontroller)

Answer (score 0):

Is the viewcontroller which you pushed into the view hierarchy overwrite the viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear accidently without calling [super viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear:animated]?

Comment: No. Every view controller called [super viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear:animated].

Answer (score 0):

You're probably accidentally calling [super viewDidLoad] inside your viewWillAppear method

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having the same issue as me: Check all your custom views to see if you're not having an infinite loop of `layoutSubviews`. This is on of the things that happens in between a `viewWillAppear` and a `viewDidAppear`.

Answer (score 0):

In my implementation I had a custom Tab bar controller and fore some reason viewDid Appear was empty, putting super calling solved it.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated) //was missing this line
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You know,if you overwrite navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate and not restore it appropriately, this bug will appear,too