# View controller freezes while pop back

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboardsegue, freeze

In my project i've got the following view controller setup :

[image]

I've got custom tabbar controller with sections ( as you can see on storyboards ) and each section has it's own navigation controller, who's view is being add as a subview ti custom tabbar controller ( with all nessesary preparations with child view controllers ).

In this architecture i also got base navigation controller - left most - it provides push segues, that covers my custom tabbar ( like Instagram does while detailing a post ). Unfortunately, sometimes viewcontrollers, that are pushed from inner controllers ( such collection view controller right-most) strangely freese and don't respond to user tap. This issue also happens when returning back from post detailing. What can cause this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it happens for a certain duration of time and view controller is able to take touches after some time? or is it not able to take any touches at all?

Comment: I may have answered it here. Do check and let me know if it solves your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/a/36637556/2538729

Comment: @sargeras - yep, some testers reported some kind of this behaviour - vc is able to intercept touches after some kind of time

Comment: I would suggest using 'Debug View Hierarchy' to check if the view controllers have any other view on top to prevent touches.... or may be app is performing some tedious sync operation while being presented... may be in viewDidLoad or similar.

Comment: @sargeras - i investigated earlier, and once i saw two pushed controllers, that freeses, but it's strange - the top one should respond to touches? And there is no view on top*(

Comment: @PenkeySuresh - nope, didn't help.

Comment: Is it only the view controller with collection view that has this freeze issue? try checking the implementation for it''s cells... may be they are the one causing issue