# iOS - App freezes when push from navigation controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I encountered this strange bug: sometimes when I push a view controller(VC1 -> VC2), the app gets frozen(It doesn't crash, just freeze). There is no blocking main thread. And when I check the View Hierarchy, the VC2 is actually under a "`UIParallaxDimmingView`". Also, the `viewDidLoad`, `viewDidAppear` are called.

How I present VC2:

```
VC *vc2 = [[VC alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc2 animated:YES];
```

So the problem is the VC2 is loaded but does not appear on screen. Here is the screen shot of the view hierarchy, the highlighted blue view is the `UIParallaxDimmingView`, and it's blocking all my VC2 contents, and the VC1 is actually under VC2...

[image]

and here is my stack trace

```
0x10016b8dc <+0>:   sub    sp, sp, #0x40             ; =0x40 
0x10016b8e0 <+4>:   stp    x29, x30, [sp, #0x30]
0x10016b8e4 <+8>:   add    x29, sp, #0x30            ; =0x30 
0x10016b8e8 <+12>:  stur   wzr, [x29, #-0x4]
0x10016b8ec <+16>:  stur   w0, [x29, #-0x8]
0x10016b8f0 <+20>:  stur   x1, [x29, #-0x10]
0x10016b8f4 <+24>:  bl     0x1004105a4               ; symbol stub for: objc_autoreleasePoolPush
0x10016b8f8 <+28>:  adrp   x1, 1044
0x10016b8fc <+32>:  add    x1, x1, #0x888            ; =0x888 
0x10016b900 <+36>:  adrp   x30, 1057
0x10016b904 <+40>:  add    x30, x30, #0xd70          ; =0xd70 
0x10016b908 <+44>:  ldur   w8, [x29, #-0x8]
0x10016b90c <+48>:  ldur   x9, [x29, #-0x10]
0x10016b910 <+52>:  ldr    x30, [x30]
0x10016b914 <+56>:  ldr    x1, [x1]
0x10016b918 <+60>:  str    x0, [sp, #0x18]
0x10016b91c <+64>:  mov    x0, x30
0x10016b920 <+68>:  str    w8, [sp, #0x14]
0x10016b924 <+72>:  str    x9, [sp, #0x8]
0x10016b928 <+76>:  bl     0x1004106c4               ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x10016b92c <+80>:  bl     0x10040fc20               ; symbol stub for: NSStringFromClass
0x10016b930 <+84>:  mov    x29, x29
0x10016b934 <+88>:  bl     0x100410718               ; symbol stub for: objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue
0x10016b938 <+92>:  mov    x9, #0x0
0x10016b93c <+96>:  ldr    w8, [sp, #0x14]
0x10016b940 <+100>: str    x0, [sp]
0x10016b944 <+104>: mov    x0, x8
0x10016b948 <+108>: ldr    x1, [sp, #0x8]
0x10016b94c <+112>: mov    x2, x9
0x10016b950 <+116>: ldr    x3, [sp]
0x10016b954 <+120>: bl     0x10040fd28               ; symbol stub for: UIApplicationMain
0x10016b958 <+124>: stur   w0, [x29, #-0x4]
0x10016b95c <+128>: ldr    x1, [sp]
0x10016b960 <+132>: mov    x0, x1
0x10016b964 <+136>: bl     0x1004106e8               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x10016b968 <+140>: ldr    x0, [sp, #0x18]
0x10016b96c <+144>: bl     0x100410598               ; symbol stub for: objc_autoreleasePoolPop
0x10016b970 <+148>: ldur   w0, [x29, #-0x4]
0x10016b974 <+152>: ldp    x29, x30, [sp, #0x30]
0x10016b978 <+156>: add    sp, sp, #0x40             ; =0x40 
0x10016b97c <+160>: ret`
```

Comment: how do you load the VC2? code snippet?

Comment: have you checked the CPU?

Comment: @HashmatKhalil please see my updated question, just the normal way, nothing fancy

Comment: You may need to share VC2's init method, plus `-viewDidLoad`, `-viewWillAppear:` and `-viewDidAppear:`.  If you're not doing anything interesting or unusual there, this sounds like an OS bug, but it seems like rather an unlikely one.

Comment: @SeamusCampbell I didn't do anything that may affect the UI, I think it is an iOS bug, coz the interesting thing is: when it freezes, and I press home button returning to home screen, then go back to the app, the VC2 just appears like normal. So there's definitely nothing blocking the main thread. So strange.

Comment: the issue sounds like as if the presentation of the VC happens in a background thread. can you check if that is not the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to find a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36503224/ios-app-freezes-on-pushviewcontroller)

So my `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` is enabled even when the current visible view controller is the only VC on the navigation stack. Simply disable that will solve the bug.

Answer (score 0):

**SWIFT 3**

```
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, didShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {


    if (navigationController.viewControllers.count > 1)
    {
         self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
        navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
         self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = nil
        navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false;
    }
}
```