# App freezing while pushing view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

Recently I've got stuck in a bug of pushing `UIViewController` to `UINavigationViewController`, and I've found the solution for it.

Bug scenario:

it doesn't matter how you push the `UIViewController` (by segue, using pushViewController, ..). In RootViewController of your NavigationViewController, try to use swipe back gesture! (nothing should happen), then try to push a ViewController into your NavigationViewController by tapping an element. => App Freezes! Here, if you capture the screen by XCode, you will find that the current visible screen is the next screen!! (but it's not!), Cpu usage and any other things are normal. **you can get out of App Freezing by just another swipe back gesture!**

Here is the solution:

In your BaseNavigationViewController (which extends `UINavigationViewController`) insert these codes (especially when you're using `UITabbarNavigationViewController`)

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
   didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
                animated:(BOOL)animate {
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
      if (self.viewControllers.count > 1) {
        self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
        self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
      } else {
        self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = nil;
        self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
      }
    }
}
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
   if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
      return self.viewControllers.count > 1;
   }
   return NO;
}
```

Do not forget to write these codes too:

in `viewDidLoad` of BaseNavigationViewController:

```
self.delegate = self;
```

and your `BaseNavigationViewController` must use these two protocols: 
`UINavigationControllerDelegate`, `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`

Comment: Is this a question or an answer?

Comment: @AuRis maybe OP faced trouble with this problem and figured he would try and help others who had it.

Comment: @OP For you to face this issue you probably have set up something incorrectly, it is not normal behavior for an app to freeze just when you push a view controller, it is also not common to set the delegate of something to itself. Delegates are used so that a class can respond to actions done in another class completely. It should already be able to detect if things have happened in it's own class.

Comment: @AuRis Actually it's problem that I faced recently, and I just wanted to help the others like me.

Comment: @AlanS you're right is not a normal behavior of pushViewController, unfortunately, it seems like a bug for iOS SDK, and it will never happen in normal cases, read the Bug scenario.

Comment: @Aliunco This situation does not happen for me. If i swipe back multiple times on the root nothing happens, as you said, but the device does not get stuck. 

I am certain that this is not a bug with the iOS SDK and that you've done something incorrectly. The issue in the first place should not happen naturally, without you having interfered in some way.

Comment: @AlanS
I've searched on my code and tried to find anything weird, which can affect this behavior and I've found something! you're right there was something wrong with the code!
you can find the bug here :
https://github.com/aliuncoBamilo/TestNavigationPushBug

Comment: If you wish to post a problem and a solution that is fine but please do it correctly. Post the issue in your question. Then post the solution as an answer below. Do not post both together in the question. Please remove the solution from your question and post it as an answer below.

Comment: This is the same issue as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36503224/ios-app-freezes-on-pushviewcontroller/36637556

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS App Freezes on PushViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36503224/ios-app-freezes-on-pushviewcontroller)