# UI freezing when push ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, navigation

I have problem to display my ViewControllers. Sometimes happens this... freezing UI while pushing new ViewController.
All UI elements created programmatically with SnapKit (in current code CameraUI class).

GIF demo: https://radikal.ru/video/VeDy5trCfNn

**Pushing Action** from origin ViewController

```
@objc func cameraAction(){
        let cameraVC = CameraViewController()
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(cameraVC, animated: true)
    }
```

**CameraViewController**

```
class CameraViewController: UIViewController{
lazy var UI = CameraUI(view: self.view, navController: self.navigationController!)
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        title = "Camera"
        addUIElements()
        setupCaptureSession()
        setupDevice()
        setupInputOutput()
        setupPreviewLayer()
        startRunningCaptureSession()
        addActions()
    }
private func addUIElements(){
        UI.addElementsToSuperView()
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not provide a lot of code, but I would venture to suggest that the problem is that you call methods that inhibit the appearance of the screen.

You should try to move some methods for camera setup to viewWillApear or viewDidAppear.

Look at this methods:

```
        setupCaptureSession()
        setupDevice()
        setupInputOutput()
        setupPreviewLayer()
        startRunningCaptureSession()
```

Comment: Even if i clear all setup you write... problem still the same.

Comment: by the way i have same problem on few controllers. Interesting one thing... i have two controllers with views and collections. All the same, just different content... One works fine (action from Tabbar), the second has same trouble (action from previous controller)

Comment: Maybe you push your controller not from the main thread? @GeorgeHeints

Comment: i tried push from 
DispatchQueue.main.async {
            push...
}
Still the same. If you have more ideas.. i will enjoy to listen)

Comment: Did you try this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36503224/ios-app-freezes-on-pushviewcontroller)

Comment: Okey, I hope this one will help you. Mention me back)